# List of dictionaries: print readable output in python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to output lots of information from a 3D package and struggling to find a good way to format the data in a nice readable format, before its synced to an online server.

I would love any advice on how to get the print output of this:

```
dicts = [
    { "Annot1": 1, "NAME": "name", "TEXT": "text" },
    { "Annot2": 2, "NAME": "name", "TEXT": "text" },
    { "Annot3": 3, "NAME": "name", "TEXT": "text" },
    { "Annot4": 4, "NAME": "name", "TEXT": "text" }
]
print "\n \n".join(str(i)+" "+str(a) for i, a in enumerate(dicts, start=1))
```

To look like the print output of this:

```
name = {
    "Annot1": 'name',
    "Annot2": 'name',
    "Annot3": 'name',
    "Annot4": 'name'
}
text = {
    "Annot1": 'text',
    "Annot2": 'text',
    "Annot3": 'text',
    "Annot4": 'text'
}
for key in sorted(name):
    print key
    print "NAME: %s" % name[key]
    print "TEXT: %s" % text[key]
    print
```

... this is what I've come up with

```
dicts = [
    { "Annotation_1": 1, "NAME": "name", "CONTENT": "text" },
    { "Annotation_2": 2, "NAME": "name", "CONTENT": "text" },
    { "Annotation_3": 3, "NAME": "name", "CONTENT": "text" },
    { "Annotation_4": 4, "NAME": "name", "CONTENT": "text" }
]

for d in dicts:
name = ''             # Or just name = 'Annot1' ?
for k in d.keys():
    if k.startswith('Annot'):
        name = k
        break
print d['Annotation'], name
print("NAME: %s" % d['NAME'])
print("CONTENT: %s" % d['CONTENT'])
print
```

and this is how I intend to input the data which will late be written to file, from my 3D application

```
dicts=[]

annotations={}
annotation[("Annotation_" + str(i))]
annotation['NAME'] = 'name'
annotation['CONTENT'] = 'content'
annotation['REF_URL'] = 'ref_url'
annotation['REF_INFO'] = 'ref_nfo' 

dicts.append(annotations)
```

this is what I've come up with so far based on the help I got here.

Is this a good way to go about it? (the initial for-range-loop is just a place holder so far)

```
annotations = []

for d in range(10):
    annotations.append(dict(
    [('ID', d+1),
    ('NAME', 'Tag Name '+str(d+1)),
    ('CONTENT', 'Note Content: This space will have a lot of text'),
    ('URL', 'ref address'),
    ('URL Info', 'url info')]
    ))

for i, a in enumerate(annotations):
    print "\nAnnotation:", "#"+str(i+1)
    print "NAME:", a['NAME']
    print "NOTE CONTENT:", a['CONTENT']
    print "Ref URL:", a['URL']
    print "URL Info:", a['URL Info']
```

Comment: (1.) You wrote 4 times `"Annot1": ` in the first code section. Typo?  (2.) Do the names (`"Annot1"`, ...) have to be extracted from dict or can they be generated (`"Annot" + str(i)`)?

Comment: @Norman, yes sorry about that, typos indeed. I've corrected them now. Yes they could all have generated count attached to them later, but might not be needed since I could use the count in the value instead.

Comment: No problem. But if those were typos, then why did you accept @Mike's answer that always accesses "Annot1"? :-)

Comment: I asked about generating the "Annot*i*" keys because extracting them from the dictionary like I do might become slow for large dicts. Also, none of our answers actually do any sorting like your example does. Is the list of dicts already sorted appropriately as in your example?

Comment: @Norman thanks well that's a good question, regarding the answer I accepted :s I'm obviously quite new here and I tried to accept both answers, which obviously doesn't work. I did play around with your code too and will post it below together with the way I'm intending to in put the dicts into the list. How would you go about extracting them from the dictionary? The reason that I have the "Annot1" etc.. in my initial code is that if I don't have that I seem to be overwriting a single dict everytime I insert a new one. ..?

Comment: oh and yes, regarding the sorted aspect. my dictionaries do come out sorted although I know that they're not sorted by default. I haven't done any particular sorting yet

Comment: *"well that's a good question"* Made my day ^^  Okay, sounds like a bug if you had an "overwriting a single dict" issue. In the last code block you posted, I see no loop appending multiple dicts to the list. Do you add them manually? Maybe you should post more code. Anyways, unless you have a reason to do so, I'd recommend using the same key name for all dicts (e.g. "id"). It's just easier, and there's really no problem adding several of those to the same list. Then, you could sort them like this: `for d in sorted(dicts, key=lambda d: d["id"]): ...`.

Comment: @Norman thanks again for your help! apologies I've had to take a quick break from this but have played around with the code and been struggling a bit to apply the lambda concept. I will post a bit more code next week to see if it might make more sense ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
dicts = [
 { "Annot1": 1, "NAME": "name", "TEXT": "text" },
 { "Annot1": 2, "NAME": "name", "TEXT": "text" },
 { "Annot1": 3, "NAME": "name", "TEXT": "text" },
 { "Annot1": 4, "NAME": "name", "TEXT": "text" }
]

for d in dicts:
    print "Annot{}".format(d["Annot1"])
    for item in ["NAME", "TEXT"]:
        print '{}: {}'.format(item, d[item])
    print
```

gives this output:

```
Annot1
NAME: name
TEXT: text

Annot2
NAME: name
TEXT: text

Annot3
NAME: name
TEXT: text

Annot4
NAME: name
TEXT: text
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you, you simply want this:

```
for d in dicts:
    name = ''             # Or just name = 'Annot1' ?
    for k in d.keys():
        if k.startswith('Annot'):
            name = k
            break
    print(name)
    print("NAME: %s" % d['NAME'])
    print("TEXT: %s" % d['TEXT'])
    print()
```